# Jsoup: Not able to get all <a> tag text

Tags: java, jsoup

```
<body>
     <a>hello</a>
     <p><a>hello1</a></p>
     <a>hello2<a>
</body>
```

I want all text of `<a>` tag but when I try, it only returns the text "hello" and "hello2".

```
System.out.println(doc.select("a").text());
```

it showing me only hello hello2 but i want hello1 also

I have read previous answer of stack-overflow regarding this issue but I'm not able to get what I want.

Comment: Not sure, but if they work like css maybe println(doc.select("p a").text());? Sounds like an ugly solution though, but I do not know JSoup and it might work ^^

Comment: if i used this println(doc.select("p a").text()); it only return hello1 but i want hello, hello1 and hello2 from one single command.

Comment: Using jsoup 1.8.3, both `select("a").text()` and `getElementsByTag("a").text()` gives me all three instances

Comment: Ya i got it,  thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following, considering jsoup seems to use css selectors.

```
 System.out.println(doc.select("a, p a").text());
```

But this is rather limited, because if you have an even further nested a tag, you'll have an issue there.

Comment: you said correctly it create an issue because i have html file which contain further nested  a tag.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that your example is malformed html. The last two `<a>` tags are not closed. Jsoup tries to understand this that way:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <a>hello</a>
  <p><a>hello1</a></p>
  <a>hello2</a>
  <a></a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Apart from this, I can't reproduce the behavior you describe.

```
System.out.println(doc.select("a").text());
```

results in

```
hello hello1 hello2
```

Maybe you use a faulty version of JSoup? My tests were done with version 1.8.3

Comment: Actually the html i written above is just an example by mistake i didn't close it but after searching lot i got my result finally.